# why generic T return Object type when i use getter in java?

Tags: java

**DTO class**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ValueDto <T>{
    @NotNull
    private String keySet;

    @NotNull
    private T value;
}
```

**call service method**

```
ValueDto valueDto = ValueDto.builder()
                .key("1234")
                .value(anotherDto)
                .build();

        service.dtoTest(valueDto);
```

**Service class**

```
public <T> void dtoTest(@Valid ValueDto valueDto) {
Test test = new Test();
        test.saveKey(valueDto.getKeySet(), valueDto.getValue());
    }
```

I want to return T type from valueDto.getValue(). but, it was returned Object type.
What is the problem?

Comment: Look at your declaration of `valueDto` - it's the raw type. You're not specifying a generic type argument anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify generic type during object creation.
Here is example with lombok builder with generic:

```java
        ValueDto<String> valueDto = ValueDto.<String>builder()
                .keySet("1234")
                .value("anotherDto")
                .build();
```